# How to Execute an Object Query in MS Access using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have an **Object Query** in MS Access named "getLicense" that will execute the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tblLicense;
```

In my C# WinForm Application, I'm trying to execute the "getLicense" Object Query in MS Access through these codes:

```
/***This does not work***/
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
myCommand.CommandText = "getLicense";
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
myReader.Read();
/************************/

/****This is working*****/
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblLicense";
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
myReader.Read();
/************************/
```

I want to manage my Queries in MS Access DB through **Object Queries**
and not in the hard coded query in C# that's why I'm trying to use the **CommandType.StoredProcedure**.

Here is the exception

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: do you get an exception? if so, what is the exception you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OleDbCommand Stored Procedure Cannot Find Access Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559190/oledbcommand-stored-procedure-cannot-find-access-query)

Comment: Did you try myCommand.CommandText = "Exec getLicense" with commandtype as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is like an execution of the MSSQL Server Stored Procedure, I have replaced the:

> `myCommand.CommandText = "getLicense";`

with this:

> `myCommand.CommandText = "EXEC getLicense";`